# Can chrome be used, from the command-line, to retrieve a URL's content to a file?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, command-line, cmd, scripting

I've been driving myself mad trying to get curl, wget, the python request module, and others, to simply get me logged in to a website and pull page text there. I can certainly request HTML from the site, but only as an anonymous user. I've spent a few hours with tricks like chrome's "copy cURL" feature, but the website in question is smart enough to defend against login playbacks.

All I want is a way, from the command-line, to do something like:

```
chrome.exe --output_to_file page.html https://www.endpoint.com/auth_access_only.html
```

Essentially, I'm looking for chrome to do for me what cURL does, but I want the command-line invocation to be executed as me. I can see how this **might** open a potential security issue, but I don't mind at all if I have to do something magical to authorize my script. I'm not looking to do anything evil - I just want to be able to write scripts that are as "me" as I am.

I guess that, if it's truly unavoidable, I could suck it up and dust off Internet Explorer. I'd really rather not do that. I'd feel so dirty.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but it's not as simple as you're thinking.

You can use the [Chrome Debugging Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) to remote-control Chrome.

You will need to write some code to make this work - I have done similar tasks using the [`chrome-remote-interface`](https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface) library for Node.js.

Make sure you understand what a [browser profile](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824) is and where your profile folder lives.

If Chrome is already running using your browser profile:  make sure it was launched with `--remote-debugging-port=9002` or similar.

If Chrome is not already running using your browser profile:  launch it with `--user-data-dir="C:\path\to\your\profile" --remote-debugging-port=9002` or similar.

The "running or not" part is a bit tricky - you cannot launch more than one Chrome instance with the same browser profile, but you need to use this user profile because your login data is stored there.  It may actually be easiest to create a separate browser profile that is just used for this automated task, and log in to the site there too.

Then, at a high level, your Node.js code will need to connect to Chrome, load the page, wait for the response, and save it to a file.  Have a look at the example code for the `chrome-remote-interface` library - you can definitely piece together what you need from there.

---

Another option which uses the same underlying technology is to use [`puppeteer`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) which is another tool to automate Chrome.  It is designed to start from a fresh profile every time.  If you do this, you'll need to script more interactions:

- Visit the site's login page
- Type the login credentials into the form and click the login button
- Visit the site's authenticated page and save it to a file.

The benefit of this approach is that the result should be more reliable, preventing issues like expired login sessions.